# C#.NET Fetch Tab Character from XML Attribute

Tags: c#

All,
**Process:**  map Flat File to Application Object.
**Meta Data:**  stored in Xml file.  Contains field name, delimter, and order number each stored in an attribute.
**Issue:** When fetching the delimiter attribute in Application code, the Tab Character (\t) comes through like this:  `\\t` (double backslash t).

**Xml Sample:**

```
<field name= "Field1" delimiter='\t' orderNum="1"/>
```

**Code Sample:**

```
attrVal = node.Attributes["delimiter"].Value;
```

**Issue:** I'm trying to split each line in the file on the delimiter.  Something like:

```
string [] delim = new string[] { attrVal };
string line = streamReader.ReadLine();  
string[] record = line.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

However, because the delimiter is `\\t`(double backslash t), the Split function doesn't recognize it.

**Questions:** Should I strip off that first backslash using substring (is that even possible since it's an escape)?  Is there a different way I should be accessing the attribute in the Xml file so it won't escape the first backslash?  Any info would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<field name= "Field1" delimiter='\t' orderNum="1"/>
```

This is interpreted as the two characters `\` and `t` and not as tab - that is your problem.

You can encode tab in XML the following way:

```
<field name= "Field1" delimiter="&#x9;" orderNum="1"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [Regex.Unescape(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx).

```
String str = "string \\nstring";
Console.WriteLine(str);

Prints: 

string \nstring
```

and

```
String str = "string \\nstring";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Unescape(str));

Prints: 

string 
string
```