# How do I retrieve tab character from database into .NET string?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table in my database that contains delimiters used for when reading files. Today I came across an issue trying to retrieve the tab character. I had originally stored the string `'\t'` in the table thinking that it would be correct but when I obtained it in C# it converted it to `'\\t'`. I then updated the value to be `CHAR(9)` using the ASCII code for tab but when I pull that out of the database C# converts it to a single space. I am not doing anything special in the data layer, just a straight-up `SqlDataReader.GetString(0)` but I need it to return the actual tab character to the client. Is there something I am missing?

**EDIT**

Some additional information based on the comments.

The data is inserted into SQL Server in a script, it does not come from a C# client. The script is:

```
UPDATE Metadata.FileType SET Delimiter = '\t' WHERE Name = 'Tab';
-- OR
UPDATE Metadata.FileType SET Delimiter = CHAR(9) WHERE Name = 'Tab';
```

If I then query the table I get `'\t'` for the first version and a space for the second. If I output the character straight to text and open it in Notepad++, click show all characters the second version shows as a single space and not a tab as expected. So that would explain why the second form returns a space within C#.

**EDIT 2**

The answers in the question that is marked as a duplicate did not work for me but the second answer to this question [C#.NET Fetch Tab Character from XML Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757079/c-net-fetch-tab-character-from-xml-attribute) did work for me:

```
var delimiter = Regex.Unescape(reader.GetString(0));
```

This then shows the required `\t` and allows the client to parse the file properly. I still do not know why `string.Format(string)` does not work for me but at least I have a working solution right now.

Comment: Ummn use linq2sql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# reading a tab character as a setting from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396450/c-sharp-reading-a-tab-character-as-a-setting-from-text-file)

Comment: @SvSv Linq to SQL uses ADO.NET as the underlying technology and would have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks @Juan I tried the solution from that answer but unfortunately it did not work for me, I still get `"\\t"` if I store `"\t"` or `" "` if I use `CHAR(9)` - even with `string.Format(value)`.

Comment: Have you _actually_ verified that your data returned from the database has changed? Did you observer the binary contents of the returned string in the memory window?

Comment: I just tested the solution locally and it works fine. There is something else going on. Are you sure `\t` is what is stored in the database? You may be viewing a representation on the debugger.

Comment: Why do you think the value is converted to `\\t` or to a single space?

Comment: By the way, not to beat on a dead horse but... there was zero reason for you to mess with it. All you had to do is store the string in its original form.